# How can I use weight painting correctly in Blender?

Tags: weight-painting

Before when I was weight painting, I noticed that after changing the weight of a bone some other bones would be dramatically changed as well. When I try to undo the unexpected weights the whole mesh becomes broken. Now, when I try to subtract the weight, instead of subtracting it adds. Can someone please help me? I've been spending hours on this!

This is my blend file:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50825

Comment: Please indicate when you're using Blender 2.8. 2.8's files can't be opened with previous versions, and 2.8 itself isn't quite the same Blender and is, for now, unfinished and unstable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have this issue is that you have Auto Normalize enabled:

[image: demo pic]

Either try to understand how to work with it (because it's honestly useful), either disable it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check to see if my problem is solved now!